# startup database not coming up srvctl database status up and runinng

Tags: oracle

Prod db not coming up when starting up.

I h

```
ave done shutdown and then now starting up but db is not coming up below error

SQL> startup
ORA-39510: CRS error performing start on instance 'TSU' on 'TSU'
CRS-5702: Resource 'ora.tsu.db' is already running on 'dztup'
CRS-0223: Resource 'ora.tsu.db' has placement error.
clsr_start_resource:260 status:223
clsrapi_start_db:start_asmdbs status:223
```

i checked the srvctl status db is running up.

Comment: its because in the same server there would be some other process from srvctl either in stop/hung state - Work around is kill the crsd process which will re-spawn and will fix the above issue. Note : Killing crsd process will not impact to other databases in the same server.

Comment: Thanks Sarat, can you please tell how to kill those crsd process commands can you provide will check and do it in prod env thanks for your help.

Comment: ps -ef|grep -i crsd.bin|grep -v grep
kill -9 <process id>